# iOS6: transfer values from one view to another using a tabViewBar

Tags: uiview, ios6, uitabbar

I develope an app in iOS6 that uses a tabBarNavigation. Tab1 is the main View. The view of Tab2 contains options that should have an effect on how data is displayed in the main view (Tab1).

Question is: How do I transfer a value from view2 to the main view? Even if I use the same viewController for both views it does not work. When I set a BOOL in view2, the BOOL has not changed in the main view... probably because there are two different instances of the controller class :-)

So, how to I do that in iOS 6?

Thanks.